# How to change windows shell/terminal/process name in Go

Tags: go, terminal

I have been searching about this for some time and I haven't found anything

[image of terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DquU.png)

is there a way to change or control the title name to something custom, if so how can I do it.

in windows command terminal

Comment: That's not a Go program, that's the Windows shell.

Comment: Yes but you run the go program with windows shell

Comment: @BrwaKurdish that is terminal specific behaviour, and would depend on what terminal you're using.

Comment: @JohnOss oh I see, im using windows command terminal for this

Comment: @BrwaKurdish I've added an answer, hopefully that works for you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `cmd.exe` specifically, you should be able to do the following

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("title", "your_title_here")
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
}
```

For other Windows-specific terminals that aren't `cmd.exe`, you can checkout [Microsoft's tabTitle tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/tutorials/tab-title).

I strongly suggest checking out that tutorial, as there are quite a lot of caveats with doing this, as the shell has full control over it's title and may overwrite it at any time.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I had to modify the code a bit for it to work I found this to be help full

c := exec.Command("cmd", "/C", "title", "your_title_here")

Comment: `cmd := exec.Command("cmd", "/C", "title", "your_title_here")` works in both cmd and PowerShell